# How to enable Require status checks to pass before merging through automation

Tags: git, github, pygithub

I was reading over PyGitHub's documentation in: https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Branch.html
and found some interesting methods that I thought might help

First I made sure that **Required status checks to pass before merging** was not enabled.
Then in my python file I had

```
branch.edit_required_status_checks(strict=True, contexts=["action-runner"])
```

When I ran the code it gives me the following error `github.GithubException.GithubException: 404 {"message": "Required status checks not enabled", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/enterprise-server@3.7/rest/reference/repos#get-status-checks-protection"}`

Based on the error, I went on Github and renabled the **require status checks to pass before merging**. When I reran the code I saw that it worked because now on Github I see that my GitHub Actions actions-runner was enabled. When I change the value of strict from True to False and ran my code, it unchecks **Require branches to be up to date before merging**.

This means I can't call `edit_required_status_checks()` unless I have **Required status checks to pass before merging enabled**. This is the same situation if I try using `get_required_status_checks()`.

However I can use `remove_required_status_checks()` to uncheck **Require status checks to pass before merging** yet I can't find a method that will do it the other way around for enabling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `branch.edit_protection(strict=True)` will toggle on `Require status checks to pass before merging` , which will then allow for `edit_required_status_checks()` to succeed.